# Fill HTML table with content by column

Tags: css, html-table

I have a set of data that I'm trying to display in a responsive grid, depending on the size of the viewport.

This data is alphabetized, and for legibility, I'd like to display it in order by column:

```
|---------|--------|--------|
| Abi     | Donald | George |
| Boris   | Ernest | Harold |
| Charlie | Frank  | Ivan   |
```

On desktop, with a wider viewport, this might look like this:

```
|-------|---------|--------|--------|------|
| Abi   | Charlie | Ernest | George | Ivan |
| Boris | Donald  | Frank  | Harold |      |
```

However, because the table is responsive, the number of columns (and therefore rows) might change.  It's easy to do this responsively with Twitter Bootstrap by row by using `.col-md-3` (for example) and letting the extra items overflow onto the next line.  However, I want to populate my table **vertically, by column**.

Is there a way to do this with only CSS (e.g., without having to reorder and calculate using Javascript)?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. You want Abi, Boris And Charlie in the  same row?

Comment: The goal is to have a responsive table where the data is filled into the table in order by column rather than by row.  Abi, Boris, and Charlie would all be in the same row if it were a very huge screen and all of the data fit into a single row.

Answer (score 1):

this is very easy, and you can still use Bootstrap, like this:

```
<div class="mydata col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><ul><li>Abi</li> <li>Boris<li> <li> Charlie</li></ul></div>
```

However, if you want the opposite, try

```
<div class="mydata col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><ul><li>Abi</li> <li>Boris<li> <li> Charlie</li></ul></div>
```

Then in your CSS

```
.mydata ul{display:block;}
.mydata li{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: I unfortunately was never able to get this working--it would always remain in one column, no matter how much data it was.